# Passing variables between functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, one that makes an Ajax request when the user loads the page, and one that will run every 5 or so seconds to update something. Using the first function, I can output a variable that I need to use in the second function.

```
function insert_last_ten() {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'freeshout/chatlog.php',
       success: function(data) {
         $("#inner-wrap").html(data);
         var first_child = $("#inner-wrap :first-child").html();
         var value = first_child.match(/(value)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/);
         var realtime = value[2];
       }
     });
    }
```

Basically, I need to use `realtime` to do something else in another function. For the sake of simplicity, let's pretend this is the second function:

```
function update() {
    alert(realtime);
}
```

How could I go about making that work?

Comment: Can you move `realtime` out to a more public scope?

Comment: Making `realtime` a global variable would be the easy way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `success` callback, cancel the timeout and start a new one using the updated value. You can pass the timeout identifier to `insert_last_ten` via argument and the `success` callback will pick it up via closure:

```
function createUpdateTimer(value, interval) {
    return setTimout(
      function () {
        alert(value); // The created function knows what value is due to closure
      }, interval);
}

function insert_last_ten(timer) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'freeshout/chatlog.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#inner-wrap").html(data);
            var first_child = $("#inner-wrap :first-child").html();
            var value = first_child.match(/(value)=["']?((?:.(?!["']?\s+(?:\S+)=|[>"']))+.)["']?/);
            var realtime = value[2];
            cancelTimer(timer); // This callbac knows what timer is due to closure
            timer = createUpdateTimer(realtime, 500);
        }
    });
}

// Start the timer:
var timer = createUpdateTimer('initial value', 500);

// Make ajax request:
insert_last_ten(timer);
```

Note that I am only beginning to familiarize myself with the good parts of JavaScript. This code is untested.

Comment: How would I go about that? I checked through jQuery docs and searched around, and couldn't really find out what you mean. =/

Comment: @Andrew: I updated my answer with an example. Closures are not in the jQuery documentation, because it's a JavaScript feature, not a jQuery feature.